# how can I relate webView and listView items using Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-webview

In my app, there is a fragment class and webView class with simple xml files. I want to click a ListView item(mail, stack etc.), then loading their URL's. I could not it. please help.
This is fragment class:

```
public class frags extends Fragment {
   final String[] items={"google", "facebook", "twitter", "mail", "stack"};
```

//there are some codes.

```
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)  {

           intent = new Intent ( context, web.class);
           startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return vw;    }
```

}

Comment: You should pass url to intent and get it in web class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Listview Click Listener Pass your Clicked Iitem Like this

```
 myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)  {

           intent = new Intent ( context, web.class);
           intent.putExtra("item_name",items.get(position));
           startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and in your **web.class** receive item name

```
Bundle b = getIntent.getExtras;
if(b.getString("item_name").equals("facebook")){
//open facebook url
}else if (b.getString("item_name").equals("twitter")){
//open twitter url
}
```

Comment: you can accept this answer so it also helpful other@Gokhan